# Get URI from holder.imageView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-viewholder

I guess i got confused, with all that URI passing, here is the think, im downloading images (using glide) to my card view, when user click the item i want to pass all card data to other fragmnet, the vars are got carried with bundle, but what about the image.

Do i really have to redownload the image again, in other fragment, or there is some way to get URI from the holder.imageview, or maybe some way to cache the image?

any advise would be appreciated!

Comment: Glide is using chaching system, it will not downloaded again once it already downloaded.

Comment: so let me get it right, if ill pass to the other fragment only the url of the img,  and ill use glide in the other fragment for listview holder.image, glide wont download it again?

Comment: yes, thats the "context" here as anchor of the cache.. It will become different it it's in another activity. And the glide cache is not only in memory but also in storage aswell

Comment: you can try to change into airplane mode, and look, the image is still loaded

Comment: wow cool, didnt know that, ill try it, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glide itself caches your images pretty effectively, so you don't have to worry about it. Alternatively, you can also pass the image as an argument to the new fragment by storing it as a bitmap first.

```
Bitmap nitmap = Glide.
    with(this).
    load("http://....").
    asBitmap().
    into(-1, -1). 
    get();
```

Then pass this bitmap as an argument.

Comment: ok ok, nice, ill try first glide cache and then bitmap conversion.

Answer (score 0):

in your holder, have a variable to store your URI (URI of saved location in your device)

Then you can simply pass the uri to your other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

use the same glide code to load image.

```
Glide.with(context).load("url").into(holder.imageview);
```